Why would a parameter I just programmatically created be read-only?
I'm programmatically creating a shared parameter via the Revit API. I am specifying a GUID and doing this as part of an add-in I am maintaining. I have recently revamped the parameter code, and that's where my troubles began, although a lot of the parameter code that sets up things like bindings has not changed.
The bindings in general are to a list that consists of "find all the Categories in document.Settings.Categories where the Category Type is not Invalid and the Category Allows Bound Parameters"
The add-in manipulates these parameters in other functionalities.
When I go to find a parameter that I have "just added" to the document, I can only find it by GUID. I cannot find it by name.
The parameter has no value (which makes sense, as I've literally just added it) and Is read-only, which makes no sense.
It is possible that I have removed this parameter before in the course of my testing. The GUID I am using for each of the 10 parameters is unique but a constant specified in my code.
What gives?

Are you able to provide some code? Without know what you are doing to add that parameter to the document, it is difficult to see what could be going on.
